# Angular-google-maps: How to show Title and Description dynamically on markers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am using Angular-google-maps, `HTML` code follows

```
  <ui-gmap-google-map center='mapData.map.center' zoom='mapData.map.zoom' 
  events="mapEvents">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="mapData.map.markers" coords="'self'">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

in `JS` calling

```
angular.extend(this, $controller('MapsMixinController', 
{$scope:$scope, map:mapData.data[0].map}));
```

`MapsMixinController` as follows. Calling this controller from js code. Markers are showing & on click able to mark.

`MapsMixinController.js`

```
/**
 * Controller providing common behaviour for the other map controllers
 */
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MapsMixinController', ['$scope', 'GeolocationService', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', 'map',
        function($scope, GeolocationService, GoogleMapApi, map) {
            var _this = this;

            $scope.mapEvents = {
                click: function(mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                    var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                    if (e.latLng) {
                        $scope.mapData.map.markers.push({
                            id: new Date().getTime(),
                            latitude: e.latLng.lat(),
                            longitude: e.latLng.lng()
                        });
                        // This event is outside angular boundary, hence we need to call $apply here
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            };

            // Returns a default map based on the position sent as parameter
            this.getDefaultMap = function(position) {
                return {
                    markers: [],
                    center: {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude
                    },
                    zoom: 14
                };
            };

            // Initialize the google maps api and configure the map
            GoogleMapApi.then(function() {
                GeolocationService().then(function(position) {
                    $scope.mapData.map = map || _this.getDefaultMap(position);
                }, function() {
                    $scope.error = "Unable to set map data"; // TODO use translate
                });
            });
        }
    ]);
```

How can I show title on mouse hover on markers? And on click how to show description on markers?

Comment: I think is just adding a new marker as said in google maps api: `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: I mean just adding title to your markers Array, then google maps api will understand it

Comment: As they say: The marker's title will appear as a tooltip.
If you need to add more info, you will need a infoWindow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Answer (score 2):

You can add title property alone with latitude and longtitude property while creating marker data.

```
    /**
 * Controller providing common behaviour for the other map controllers
 */
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MapsMixinController', ['$scope', 'GeolocationService', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', 'map',
        function($scope, GeolocationService, GoogleMapApi, map) {
            var _this = this;

            $scope.mapEvents = {
                click: function(mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                    var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                    if (e.latLng) {
                        $scope.mapData.map.markers.push({
                            id: new Date().getTime(),
                            latitude: e.latLng.lat(),
                            longitude: e.latLng.lng(),
                            title: "Mouse over text"
                        });
                        // This event is outside angular boundary, hence we need to call $apply here
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            };

            // Returns a default map based on the position sent as parameter
            this.getDefaultMap = function(position) {
                return {
                    markers: [],
                    center: {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude
                    },
                    zoom: 14
                };
            };

            // Initialize the google maps api and configure the map
            GoogleMapApi.then(function() {
                GeolocationService().then(function(position) {
                    $scope.mapData.map = map || _this.getDefaultMap(position);
                }, function() {
                    $scope.error = "Unable to set map data"; // TODO use translate
                });
            });
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Sathish, your plunkr is about "marker" not "markers". None of the answers solves how to show a diferent title for each marker in "markerS"